# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException while running mlunittest

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Below error is throwing while running mlunittest

Execution failed for task ':mlUnitTest'.

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: build\test-results\marklogic-unit-test\TEST-SampleTestSuite.xml

Comment: any one knows what is the issue

Comment: There's no much detail to go on in the question.  The error message seems to suggest that a file isn't being produced by some previous step in the build. Maybe it is an issue with the definition of a Gradle build?

Comment: when i am running the mlunittest, i am getting test results but i am getting the error while the job is writing the test results the file

Comment: @ehennum I am observing the same on Windows environment. mlUnitTest completes successfully, but when it tries to write results, it throws this issue. Nothing fancy, just the example test. Tested with ml-gradle 4.1.1

Comment: Powershell, and Git Bash, same results. Also using unitTestResultsPath makes no difference either. Dir is created, but XML does not show up, and error is thrown..

Answer (score 0):

Issue is only writing test results to build directory.
use -PunitTestResultsPath parameter to write the test results in a different directory while running mlunittest

Comment: This didn't seem to help in my case. It kept complaining about the XML results not being found, despite the fact that the tests complete successfully.